# fmin_cg: get a ValueError because of type mismatch

Tags: scipy

Executing the following code gives a ValueError:

```
def f(theta):
    theta = theta.reshape(2, 1)
    return np.linalg.norm(x*theta -y)**2

def fprime(theta):
    theta = theta.reshape(2,1)
    return (x.T*(x*theta - y))

x = np.matrix('1, 2; 3, 4; 5, 6')
y = np.matrix('4; 2; 1')
thetainit = np.matrix('0; 0')

scipy.optimize.fmin_cg(f, np.ravel(thetainit), fprime=fprime)
```

But the dimensions are ok and the x0 argument for fmin_cg is flattened using np.ravel as described in the documentation. Here the error message:

```
   1169     gnorm = vecnorm(gfk, ord=norm)
   1170     while (gnorm > gtol) and (k < maxiter):
-> 1171         deltak = numpy.dot(gfk, gfk)
   1172 
   1173         try:
```

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Try using np.array instead of np.matrix

Comment: Tryied the following:

`def f(theta):
    theta = theta.reshape(2, 1)
    return np.linalg.norm(x.dot(theta) -y)**2

def fprime(theta):
    theta.shape = (2,1)
    return (x.T.dot(x.dot(theta) - y))

x = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]])
y = np.array([[4], [2], [1]])
thetainit = np.array([[0],[0]])

scipy.optimize.fmin_cg(f, np.ravel(thetainit), fprime=fprime) `

Got the following error:
`ValueError: shapes (2,1) and (2,1) not aligned: 1 (dim 1) != 2 (dim 0)`

Comment: Sorry with my former comment. I had problems with editing notes.

I got the same error as before: `ValueError: shapes (2,1) and (2,1) not aligned: 1 (dim 1) != 2 (dim 0)`

Answer (score 0):

This code works:

```
def f(theta):
    theta = theta.reshape(2, 1)
    return np.linalg.norm(x*theta -y)**2
#    return np.linalg.norm(x*theta -y)**2

def fprime(theta):
    theta = theta.reshape(2,1)
    g = np.array(x.T*(x*theta - y)).flatten()
    return g

x = np.matrix('1, 2; 3, 4; 5, 6')
y = np.matrix('4; 2; 1')
thetainit = np.matrix('0; 0')

scipy.optimize.fmin_cg(f, np.ravel(thetainit), fprime=fprime)
```

The crucial point was to add 'flatten()'!